# Extract field and number of occurrences per line

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep

I have this file:

```
John Green', 'Age: 32', 'State: New York', 'Total cars: 2', 'Manufacter: General Motor', 'Model: Pontiac', 'Year: 2000', 'Manufacter: Ford Motor', 'Model: Endeavour', 'Year: 2010
Peter Jones', 'Age: 20', 'State: Florida', 'Total cars: 0
Richard Smith', 'Age: 44', 'State: Illinois ', 'Total cars: 1', 'Manufacter: Toyota', 'Model: Yaris', 'Year: 2005
Brian Brown', 'Age: 42', 'State: Texas', 'Total cars: 0
Vincent Osmnod', 'Age: 39', 'State: Maryland', 'Total cars: 1', 'Manufacter: Fiat', 'Model: 500X', 'Year: 2015
```

I can use awk to extract the 4th field
and if I want to get the number of occurences of `', '` per line I use the script:

```
grep -o -n "', '" file | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq -c
```

this command also gives me the number of line

```
  9 1
  3 2
  6 3
  3 4
  6 5
```

so I can get the results separately

My desired output is:

```
Total cars: 2 |9 1
Total cars: 0 |3 2
Total cars: 1 |6 3
Total cars: 0 |3 4
Total cars: 1 |6 5
```

I tried with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1
count=0
while read LINE
do
        OUTP1=$(awk -F"', '" '{print $4" |"}' $LINE)
        OUTP2=$(grep -o -n "', '" $LINE1 | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq -c)
        echo "$OUTP1 $OUTP2"
done < $FILENAME
```

and it gives me this output:

```
awk: cannot open John (No such file or directory)
       3 1
      6 2
      3 3
      6 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -v FS="', '" '{print $4 " |"NF-1 " " NR}' file
```

If you have blank lines in `file`, you may want to use:

```
$ awk -v FS="', '" 'NF >= 1 {print $4 " |"NF-1 " " NR}' file
Total cars: 2 |9 1
Total cars: 0 |3 2
Total cars: 1 |6 3
Total cars: 0 |3 4
Total cars: 1 |6 5
```

This relies on the use of `', '` as field separator, so if a line ends with that combination of characters the last field will be considered empty. That may be a corner case for you. If so, please, mention it so this and other solutions can be adapted.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F "," '{print $4}'"{o=gsub(/', '/,$0);print o,NR}" filename |sed -e  "N;s/\n/|/g" -e "s/'//g"
```

output

```
 Total cars: 2|9 1
 Total cars: 0|3 2
 Total cars: 1|6 3
 Total cars: 0|3 4
 Total cars: 1|6 5
```